# CSF blocking ethereum traffic, despite valid config

Tags: firewall

This is to document a problem I had with CSF (ConfigServer Firewall) today that cost me a good couple hours.

The problem was that my Ethereum node communicating on port 30303 was being blocked, even though I had added the ports to my config file. It seemed to be working just fine, blocking bad logins and otherwise communications to and from my machine, but when I added new ports to the TCP_IN, TCP_OUT, UDP_IN and UDP_OUT lists and ran `sudo systemctl restart csf`, they wouldn't take effect.

See answer for solution....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was frustrating: `systemctl` didn't actually refresh the iptables rules. Only `csf -ra` would do that. So after several hours of beating my head against the wall, I finally ran `csf -ra` just for kicks and everything came up.